# How to apply maximum value to a whole group using Stata

Tags: stata

I want to `generate` a variable `max_count` wherein, for a given group ID, if the value of `count` for the current year is higher than for the previous year then `max_count` takes the value for the current year. The value for the current year will be applied to the succeeding years until a higher value than that in the current year occurs. For instance, in the example below for ID 2, the value of `count` in 2001 is 10 but the succeeding years (2002 and 2003) have values less than 10 (i.e. 2 and 4) so 2002 and 2003 then take the value of 10 (the highest value after 2001).

I used this Stata code but it doesn't work:

```
bysort id (Year): gen max_count=max(count, count[_n-1])
```

The highest value is only applied to the immediately succeeding year and not to all succeeding years.

```
ID  Year    count   max_count
1   2000    5          5
1   2001    0          5
1   2002    3          5
1   2003    7          7
2   2000    5          5
2   2001    10        10
2   2002    2         10
2   2003    4         10
3   2000    2         2
3   2001    5         5
3   2002    9         9
3   2003    6         9
```

Comment: Subtle wording issue: the value _for_ the current year is not the same as the value _of_ the current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear 
input ID    Year    count   max_count
    1   2000    5          5
    1   2001    0          5
    1   2002    3          5
    1   2003    7          7
    2   2000    5          5
    2   2001    10        10
    2   2002    2         10
    2   2003    4         10
    3   2000    2         2
    3   2001    5         5
    3   2002    9         9
    3   2003    6         9
end 

bysort ID (Year) : gen wanted = count[1]
by ID : replace wanted = max(wanted[_n-1], count) if _n > 1 

list, sepby(ID)

     +---------------------------------------+
     | ID   Year   count   max_co~t   wanted |
     |---------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   2000       5          5        5 |
  2. |  1   2001       0          5        5 |
  3. |  1   2002       3          5        5 |
  4. |  1   2003       7          7        7 |
     |---------------------------------------|
  5. |  2   2000       5          5        5 |
  6. |  2   2001      10         10       10 |
  7. |  2   2002       2         10       10 |
  8. |  2   2003       4         10       10 |
     |---------------------------------------|
  9. |  3   2000       2          2        2 |
 10. |  3   2001       5          5        5 |
 11. |  3   2002       9          9        9 |
 12. |  3   2003       6          9        9 |
     +---------------------------------------+
```

There is a detailed discussion of how to get such records (the maximum or minimum so far is the "record", as in sport) in [this Stata FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/maximum-and-minimum-of-sequence/).

For a one-line solution, install `rangestat` from SSC and then

```
rangestat (max) WANTED = count, int(Year . 0) by(ID)
```

The problem of when the record occurred is naturally related:

```
by ID : gen when = Year[1]
by ID : replace when = cond(wanted > wanted[_n-1], Year, when[_n-1]) if _n > 1
```